# "General manager" in French

Tags: choix-de-mot, professions

I'm trying to translate "General manager" into French. Naturally, it would be "manager général", but when I search for it on Google, nothing shows up. It seems like this is not a correct translation.

Could anyone help me translate this word correctly?

Comment: Manager -> [*directeu*r](http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/anglais-francais/manager). [General manager](http://www.linguee.fr/anglais-francais/traduction/general+manager.html) -> *directeur général*. Dictionaries can sometimes be helpful! Google isn't a dictionary.

Comment: @Laure Comme je l'indique, il ne faut pas traduire mot-à-mot ;)

Answer (score 2):

Laure was right, you have to translate *"manager"*.

But *"[directeur général](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directeur_g%C3%A9n%C3%A9ral)"* is a [CEO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chief_executive_officer) in english, so it is not what you are looking for.

---

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_manager) definition of general manager is :

> Any executive who has overall responsibility for managing both the revenue and cost elements of a company's income statement, known as profit & loss (P&L) responsibility.

The translation which is the closest in my mind is **[Directeur financier](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directeur_financier)** because he is in charge of :

- > d'optimiser la gestion des sources de capitaux et leurs emplois, dans une optique de rentabilité et de maîtrise du risque,
- > d'assurer les relations avec les apporteurs de fonds (propriétaires ou actionnaires, banques, marchés financiers…),
- > de rendre compte de la situation financière auprès du Directeur général, du Conseil d'administration, des autorités de surveillance (par ex. l'AMF), des auditeurs, des agences de notation financière,
- > de préparer les budgets et de suivre leur exécution en collaboration avec le contrôleur de gestion,
- > de fournir des simulations de rentabilité et de risque financier comme aide à la décision pour les projets d'investissement importants et de mettre en perspective les grands équilibres de l'entreprise ou de l'institution.
- > de préparer et mettre en œuvre les opérations financières importantes (émissions de titres, introduction en bourse, fusion-acquisition),
- > le plus souvent, de superviser la comptabilité, la trésorerie, les questions fiscales, le contrôle des risques (notamment risques de taux, de change, de liquidité, de contrepartie).

Comment: .... et pourtant http://www.linguee.fr/anglais-francais/traduction/general+manager.html ne se prive pas du mot à mot...

Comment: Qui a dit que linguee proposait une traduction de qualité? Personnellement quand je l'utilise, c'est uniquement pour me faire une idée.

Comment: @YohannV. d'accord, mais qu'il n'y ait *aucun* directeur financier laisse penser que les directeurs généraux sont issus de la finance chez les anglo saxon,

Comment: @cl-r C'est pour ça que je n'ai pas essayé de traduire mais de me référer aux attributs du poste

Comment: @Chop PDG n'est pas l’agrégat de deux postes? P et DG? :p

Comment: @YohannV. En effet, au temps pour moi. Wiki est par ailleurs d'accord avec toi sur la traduction de « _CEO_ » par « DG ».  

Citation intéressante : « _In many cases, the general manager of a business is given a different formal title or titles. **Most corporate managers holding the titles of chief executive officer (CEO) or president, for example, are the general managers** of their respective businesses._ » (source : [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_manager))

Comment: @Chop Oui, cl-r me le dit aussi, cependant, je cherche à donner une traduction adéquate d'un poste et pas à faire une étude approfondie sur la répartition des responsabilités entre la société française et anglaise (voire américaine). ^^'

Comment: @Amphiteóth Ce n'est pas une opinion, mais un problème de traduction et d’intelligibilité : la véritable question est de savoir si  *General Manager* représente la même fonction d'un langage à l'autre ; d'un coté de l'eau (Manche ou Atlantique) on à l'idée de financier (et que de cela),d'où la  réponse de Yohann, de l'autre on a la 'french touch' qui pour faire traverser une idée, intègre dans la Direction Générale, les Directions Financières, avec leur comptables, auditeurs, contrôleurs... quitte à noyer dans une définition englobante les spécificités sous entendues dans le monde anglo-saxon.

Comment: @cl-r Merci, la question devrait être précisée; mais j'en ai traité dans ma note 1 ainsi qu'indirectement avec le lien vers [pdg](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8871474). Si un anglophone dit "general manager", les chances qu'il désigne une unité administrative au sein d'une entreprise sont quasi nulles; il parle assurément (en France) du "président du conseil d'administration" mais sans la présidence, il parle de Tim Cook chez Apple. S'il parle de direction générale + finances/vente/RH etc., ce ne sera jamais selon moi sans préciser i.e. _general manager-resale_.

Answer (score 2):

Il s'agit de terminologie : [*FranceTerme*](http://www.culture.fr/franceterme/result/%28page_count%29/35?francetermeSearchTerme=manager&francetermeSearchDomaine=0&francetermeSearchSubmit=rechercher&action=search) donne pour *manager*... *chef*, *dirigeant*, *directeur*, *gestionnaire* ou *responsable* - avec un complément du nom selon le type ou le contexte; on a même le *manageur* (pas au [Québec](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=26526884) : *gestionnaire*, *cadre*). Au *GDT*, on a pour *general manager* le *chef de la direction* ou le [*directeur général*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=1299292), tel qu'on en a traité en [commentaire](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/14170/general-manager-in-french#comment26780_14170) : « *Personne habituellement choisie parmi les membres du conseil d'administration d'une société qui répond, par délégation, de la marche de cette société. Le plus souvent, et selon les entreprises, le chef de la direction est tantôt le [président-directeur général](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8871474) (le président), tantôt le président du conseil d'administration.* » (GDT). <sup>1</sup> (voir aussi à la [*BDL*](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?T1=chief&T3.x=0&T3.y=0)). [*Collins*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-french/general-manager?showCookiePolicy=true) a aussi le *directeur général*. Au *Termium*, on a des emplois sur-spécialisés, mais en consultant [*general manager*](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&index=ent&__index=ent&srchtxt=GENERAL%20MANAGER&comencsrch.x=0&comencsrch.y=0), [*chief executive officer*](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&index=ent&__index=ent&srchtxt=CEO)(sens 9), et inversement [*directeur général*](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&index=frt&__index=frt&srchtxt=DIRECTEUR%20GENERAL) on confirme certainement le ***directeur général***.

---

Typically, if this is a private sector *general manager* who has CEO-like functions and sits on or is named by the board, then this is a **directeur général** (preferably le *chef de la direction* in Québec). Note that if this is a *bank* manager, or with North American football, it may still be a kind of *directeur*. The *general manager* should not be translated in a vacuum; beyond the classic corporate setup description, one should look at the context, differences between private/public sector, commercial focus and such, while adopting a systematic approach which should be consistent with both prior usage and jurisdiction specifics.

---

<sub>1. En entreprise, une personne nommée [*directrice générale de la vente au détail*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=9898774) n'est pas une *directrice générale* au sens de *chef de la direction*, ne siège probablement pas au conseil etc.; mais ce peut être la traduction du *general manager-resale*. Dans d'autres contextes spécialisés, un [*manager*](https://nimbus.mcgill.ca/pld-ddp/dictionary/show/16251?source=OBLEN) peut même être assimilé à un *[gérant](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=2067)*, un délégué, ou plus généralement à un *mandataire*, même si les cas usuels où on l'utilise sont souvent erronés (ex. gérant(x) de banque; mais, correct, *directeur gérant* au football).</sub>